# Call a function for each observation for a given column of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a DF as follows :

```
A    B   C
1    11   12
1    9    NA
1    17   NA
2    16   11
2    8    NA
2    6    12
3    14   13
3    16   NA
3    9    12
```

I need to replace the NA by calling a function for each missing value in column 3.

The function simply calculates the mean of column 1 where A=A of the missing observation.

For instance the missing value of row 3 would be (11+9+17)/3

Is there pattern that enables me to do this without looping through the table?  Kind of like..

```
missingValue<-function(df,A){

   missingValue<-mean(df[,2)<-df[,1]=A)

} 

if (is.na(df[,3])) {
     call missingValue
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not quite clear.... Would row 2 and row 3 have the same value?

Comment: @AnandaMahto yes, in the case of the sample data, but of course my real data is much bigger.

Comment: Then you should go with my option--it's the fastest :-)

Comment: @LeeJH--I didn't *really* mean for you to switch the accepted answer....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an obvious use case for `ave`. No looping required.

```
d <- read.table(text = "A    B   C
1    11   12
1    9    NA
1    17   NA
2    16   11
2    8    NA
2    6    12
3    14   13
3    16   NA
3    9    12", header = TRUE)

d$C[is.na(d$C)] <- ave(d$B, d$A, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))[is.na(d$C)]
```

The result:

```
> d
  A  B        C
1 1 11 12.00000
2 1  9 12.33333
3 1 17 12.33333
4 2 16 11.00000
5 2  8 10.00000
6 2  6 12.00000
7 3 14 13.00000
8 3 16 13.00000
9 3  9 12.00000
```

Comment: Sweet; I was thinking of 'do.call by' combination :(

Answer (score 3):

Assuming @Thomas is correct about your expected result, you could also look at `replace`.

In the interest of sharing alternatives, here's `replace` with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(DF)[, C := as.numeric(C)][, C := replace(
  C, is.na(C), mean(B)), by = A][]
#    A  B        C
# 1: 1 11 12.00000
# 2: 1  9 12.33333
# 3: 1 17 12.33333
# 4: 2 16 11.00000
# 5: 2  8 10.00000
# 6: 2  6 12.00000
# 7: 3 14 13.00000
# 8: 3 16 13.00000
# 9: 3  9 12.00000
```

---

You can also use `by = .EACHI` after creating a `data.table` to get the values from, like this:

```
DF <- as.data.table(DF)
D2 <- setkey(DF, A)[, mean(B), by = A]
DF[, C := as.numeric(C)][D2, C := replace(C, is.na(C), V1), by = .EACHI][]
```

This turns out to be faster than the previous approach.

Comment: Yeah that `as.numeric` is a real pain. That's why I didn't post that answer earlier. I'm surprised that `data.table` now forces the original column type by default instead of just giving a warning

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I was tempted to just add it as a new column :-)

Comment: Yeah me too. But then decided that this whole thing is just to much of a a mess for such a simple question and Thomases answer is probably good enough for this case. (+1) for `replace` never heard of it before.

Comment: Thanks all for commenting.  These patterns are very powerful.  Not just for missing values but there are many instances where there needs to call a function if a condition is present.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dplyr approach (using @Thomas's data):

```
require(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(C = ifelse(is.na(C), mean(B, na.rm = TRUE), C))

#Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
#Groups: A
#
#  A  B        C
#1 1 11 12.00000
#2 1  9 12.33333
#3 1 17 12.33333
#4 2 16 11.00000
#5 2  8 10.00000
#6 2  6 12.00000
#7 3 14 13.00000
#8 3 16 13.00000
#9 3  9 12.00000
```